# Retrieve data from an IActionResult?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I have to call a function returning IActionResult, and I would like to retrieve and parse the data in it. Is it possible?

Comment: Why don't you parse your data in controller?

Comment: IActionResult is an interface used by the framework to send response messages through the pipeline. It was not meant to be used outside of that. If you a calling functions directly that return IActionResult, then consider that a design issue and should review the current design of the system in question. Provide more information to clarify exactly what it is you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Thanks, @Nkosi! I just wanted to make sure before making changes

Comment: @LesterJones IActionResult are typically returned by Controller actions which are called by the framework to handle requests. Still trying to figure out why you would need to parse the data within. Is this for a unit test per say? If so then that is a whole different topic but without proper clarification of what it is you want to do there is not much help we can offer.

Comment: The IActionResult I was retrieving should contain a List<List<object>>, and that data will be used and flattened to be returned again as an IActionResult in another method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IActionResult is an interface.  The classes implementing that interface all have different data payloads.  So you would need to look at the underlying class rather than the interface, which provides no way of accessing this data.  Equally, each class would need to be interrogated in a manner specific to that class.